# Ubuntu 22.04 display color calibration problem

Tags: display, system-settings, color-management, icc

Preface. I just upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 from 20.04 and wish to use my SpyderX colorimer to calibrate my two displays (one is laptop built-in, the other is Philips 273V on HDMI).

On 20.04 the SpyderX wasn't supported natively by Ubuntu, so my steps were

1. Downloaded the latest Argyll binary distribution, v.2.3.1, unpacked it and made binaries accessible for launch from shell prompt.
2. Found the *(ancient and probably abandoned)* DisplayCAL 3.8.9.3 .deb (for Ubuntu 19) and installed it, it worked Ok on 20.04.
3. Calibrated and profiled my screens with DisplayCAL/Argyll, acquired two ICC profiles for them, and imported these into the "Color" settings tab appropriately.

While both profiles were installed Ok and `colord` has become aware of them, one problem persisted: the X atom didn't return the same profile. To test this, I used the `darktable-cmstest` utility which comes with the `darktable` photo editor.

Ok, I took the `dispwin` utility from Argyll and installed appropriate profiles with it:

```
# laptop screen is display 1
$ dispwin -d 1 -I B173HW02\ #2\ 2022-06-25\ 17-36\ 150cdm²\ 0.3203x\ 0.3306y\ 0.02cdm²\ 2.2\ S\ XYZLUT+MTX.icc
# Philips on HDMI is display 2
$ dispwin -d 2 -I PHL\ 273V7\ #1\ 2022-06-25\ 15-00\ 150cdm²\ D6500\ 0.02cdm²\ 2.2\ S\ XYZLUT+MTX.icc
```

Ok, now `darktable-cmstest` reported that I am Ok:

```
eDP-1-1 the X atom and colord returned the same profile
    X atom: _ICC_PROFILE (1665040 bytes)
        description: B173HW02 #2 2022-06-25 17-36 150cdm2 0.3203x 0.3306y 0.02cdm2 2.2 S XYZLUT+MTX
    colord: "/var/lib/colord/icc/B173HW02 #2 2022-06-25 17-36 150cdm² 0.3203x 0.3306y 0.02cdm² 2.2 S XYZLUT+MTX.icc"
        description: B173HW02 #2 2022-06-25 17-36 150cdm2 0.3203x 0.3306y 0.02cdm2 2.2 S XYZLUT+MTX

HDMI-1-2    the X atom and colord returned the same profile
    X atom: _ICC_PROFILE_1 (1005024 bytes)
        description: PHL 273V7 #1 2022-06-25 15-00 150cdm2 D6500 0.02cdm2 2.2 S XYZLUT+MTX
    colord: "/home/stesin/.local/share/icc/PHL 273V7 #1 2022-06-25 15-00 150cdm² D6500 0.02cdm² 2.2 S XYZLUT+MTX.icc"
        description: PHL 273V7 #1 2022-06-25 15-00 150cdm2 D6500 0.02cdm2 2.2 S XYZLUT+MTX

Your system seems to be correctly configured
```

Well, the only thing is, this consistency didn't persist between login, so I just made a tiny script which is executed at login, only 2 lines:

```
#!/bin/sh
dispwin -d 1 -L
dispwin -d 2 -L
```

and was happy with it. But back to 22.04.

My hope was, that the 22.04 "Color" settings tab will recognize my SpyderX and make its own calibration. Indeed, the device was recognized, and the test patch appeared on the screen to be measured, but clicking the "Start" button produced the error message about an "Unrecognizable error" and inability to continue the process. Epic FAIL. Does anyone have any explanation, why did it fail?

Ok, I still have my (good!) profiles made in 20.04, I installed them into 22.04 "Color" settings tab, and once again the same story: while `colord` has become aware of these, the X Atom (display LUT) wasn't. Again my question, why?

Yes, my "hack" with `dispwin -d 1 -I myprofile.icc` and the script still works in 22.04 so nothing fatal happened, but I am curious, why no actual improvement in 22.04 compared to 20.04?

Thanks! Regards, Andreas