# Ubuntu 20.04; how to import a color profile

Tags: monitor, color-management

I'd appreciate help to find a description that actually works for 20.04 as these three pages have the same text:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/20.04/ubuntu-help/color-howtoimport.html.en
- https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/color-howtoimport.html.en
  for 22.04
- https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/color-howtoimport.html.en   which apparently is for 23.04

For starters there is no `Add profile` in my long standing and stable 20.04. (ref to texts above)

I have a profile created with

```
$ flatpak list
...
DisplayCAL        net.displaycal.DisplayCAL       3.8.9.3 ...
```

... that I cannot figure out how to get into use.

```
$ dispwin -d 1 profile-name #fails to install the profile
```

Adding `-D` doesn't appear to tell about any failures... just that it "succeeds", at the very end.

oh...

```
Dispwin: Warning - new_dispwin: Expected VideoLUT depth 11 doesn't match actual 10
new_dispwin: DirectColor fdepth 8, rdepth 11, ndepth 10, edepth 16, r/g/b shifts 16 8 0
```

... in the midst of it; but would a warning be critical enough to stop it?

---

The actual dispwin run:

```
$ dispwin -D2 -d 1 -I profile-name # Long complicated name replaced
get_a_display called with ix 0
get_displays using 1 XRandR Screens
XRRGetCrtcInfo of Screen 0 CRTC 0 has 1 Outputs Valid Mode
Checking XRandR 1.2 VideoLUT access
Adding Screen 0 CRTC 0 Output 0
Display 0 name = ':1.0'
Root atom '_ICC_PROFILE'
Got EDID for display
XRRGetCrtcInfo of Screen 0 CRTC 1 has 0 Outputs No Mode
CRTC skipped as it has no mode or no outputs
XRRGetCrtcInfo of Screen 0 CRTC 2 has 0 Outputs No Mode
CRTC skipped as it has no mode or no outputs
XRRGetCrtcInfo of Screen 0 CRTC 3 has 0 Outputs No Mode
CRTC skipped as it has no mode or no outputs
XRRGetCrtcInfo of Screen 0 CRTC 4 has 0 Outputs No Mode
CRTC skipped as it has no mode or no outputs
XRRGetCrtcInfo of Screen 0 CRTC 5 has 0 Outputs No Mode
CRTC skipped as it has no mode or no outputs
XRRGetCrtcInfo of Screen 0 CRTC 6 has 0 Outputs No Mode
CRTC skipped as it has no mode or no outputs
 Selected ix 0 ':1.0' Monitor 1, Output eDP-1-1 at 0, 0, width 1920, height 1080'
new_dispwin called
using ucmm for profile installation
new_dispwin: Opened display ':1.0' OK
Dispwin: Warning - new_dispwin: Expected VideoLUT depth 11 doesn't match actual 10
new_dispwin: DirectColor fdepth 8, rdepth 11, ndepth 10, edepth 16, r/g/b shifts 16 8 0
dispwin_get_ramdac called
Getting gamma using Randr 1.2
dispwin_get_ramdac returning OK
Saved original VideoLUT
new_dispwin: return successfully
dispwin_install_profile 'profile-name'
Setting _ICC_PROFILE property
dispwin_set_ramdac called
Setting gamma using Randr 1.2
dispwin_set_ramdac returning OK
dispwin_del called
dispwin_set_ramdac called
Setting gamma using Randr 1.2
dispwin_set_ramdac returning OK
dispwin_set_ramdac called
Setting gamma using Randr 1.2
dispwin_set_ramdac returning OK
Restored original ramdac
About to close display
finished

$
```

---

Found descriptions and seemingly related info:

- 2015-ish:
  [Import .icm color profile from Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/571423/import-icm-color-profile-from-windows)
- 2017-ish: *(hmm... need to try one there)*
  [How do you set system display color profiles in Xubuntu and Lubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/199661/how-do-you-set-system-display-color-profiles-in-xubuntu-and-lubuntu)
- Related, stating success for 20.04:
  [Ubuntu 22.04 display color calibration problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1421781/ubuntu-22-04-display-color-calibration-problem)
- bugzilla, redhat fedora, closed as "old", still exists(?):
  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1372046
- DisplayCal discussion:
  https://sourceforge.net/p/dispcalgui/discussion/932493/thread/d34dcfb8/

---

Attempting use `colormgr`:

```
$ colormgr get-devices-by-kind display 
Object Path:   /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_LG_Display_hannu_1000
Owner:         hannu
Created:       april 22 2023, 10:55:40 AM
Modified:      april 22 2023, 11:57:35 AM
Type:          display
Enabled:       Yes
Embedded:      Yes
Model:         ROG Strix G731GU G731GU
Vendor:        ASUSTeK
Serial:        unknown
Scope:         temp
Colorspace:    rgb
Device ID:     xrandr-LG Display
Profile 1:     icc-872195e4138bb957759682f72dc25e78
               /home/hannu/.local/share/icc/edid-58ca53ac7e2a452fe10e1e7100e16186.icc
Profile 2:     icc-470b65b1eb4cb2e297533d97643e38ab
               /var/lib/gdm3/.local/share/icc/edid-58ca53ac7e2a452fe10e1e7100e16186.icc
Profile 3:     icc-49fd7c8b33ac3fe8121f6a9f5b480cd4
               /home/hannu/.local/share/icc/step4.icc
Metadata:      OutputEdidMd5=58ca53ac7e2a452fe10e1e7100e16186
Metadata:      OutputPriority=primary
Metadata:      XRANDR_name=eDP-1-1
Metadata:      OwnerCmdline=/usr/libexec/gsd-color 

$ ll 
total 796
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hannu hannu 811088 2023-04-22 13:42 step4.icc

$ colormgr device-add-profile  /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_LG_Display_hannu_1000 step4.icc 
profile id 'step4.icc' does not exist

$ colormgr device-add-profile "xrandr-LG Display" step4.icc 
profile id 'step4.icc' does not exist
```

Based on "desc" fields visible in `strings step4.icc`, also in text fields in DisplayCal (GUI) when creating the profile, and also as original filename:

```
$ mv step4.icc '2023-04-22 11-07 -- LP173WFG-SPB1 #1  2.2 VF-F XYZLUT+MTX'

$ ll
total 800
-rw-r--r-- 1 hannu hannu 811088 2023-04-22 13:07 '2023-04-22 11-07 -- LP173WFG-SPB1 #1  2.2 VF-F XYZLUT+MTX'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hannu hannu   1372 2021-03-11 19:04  edid-58ca53ac7e2a452fe10e1e7100e16186.icc

$ colormgr device-add-profile "xrandr-LG Display" 2023-04-22\ 11-07\ --\ LP173WFG-SPB1\ #1\ \ 2.2\ VF-F\ XYZLUT+MTX
profile id '2023-04-22 11-07 -- LP173WFG-SPB1 #1  2.2 VF-F XYZLUT+MTX' does not exist

$ colormgr device-add-profile "xrandr-LG Display" "2023-04-22\ 11-07\ --\ LP173WFG-SPB1\ #1\ \ 2.2\ VF-F\ XYZLUT+MTX"
profile id '2023-04-22\ 11-07\ --\ LP173WFG-SPB1\ #1\ \ 2.2\ VF-F\ XYZLUT+MTX' does not exist

$
```

---

One more thing to try:
https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Monitor_profilieren_mit_ArgyllCMS/

---

Comment: FYI:  The page https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/color-howtoimport.html.en is a *touch* closer to your system, *stable* being the latest *stable* release; and *lts* being the latest LTS release; ie. 22.04 page

Comment: Well, it is the very same text. :-I

Comment: The page for 20.04 is still there; https://help.ubuntu.com/20.04/ubuntu-help/color-howtoimport.html.en

Comment: So found it, but no help from there - same text again

Comment: (Added -I option, that made dispwin actually say `dispwin_install_profile 'profile-name'`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, some progress...
Moving the icc file to colord's stash, renaming it to a shorter name, then...

```
$ cd /usr/share/color/icc/colord 

$ sudo mv '2023-04-22 11-07 -- LP173WFG-SPB1 #1  2.2 VF-F XYZLUT+MTX' \  
step4brightness.icc

$ colormgr find-profile-by-filename step4brightness.icc
Object Path:   \  
/org/freedesktop/ColorManager/profiles/icc_4c3bbee33ae61d44bf4323afcb12a0a5

Owner:         root
Format:        ColorSpace..
Title:         2023-04-22 11-07 -- LP173WFG-SPB1 #1  2.2 VF-F XYZLUT+MTX
Qualifier:     RGB..
Type:          display-device
Colorspace:    rgb
Gamma Table:   Yes
System Wide:   Yes
Filename:      /usr/share/color/icc/step4brightness.icc
Profile ID:    icc-4c3bbee33ae61d44bf4323afcb12a0a5
Metadata:      FILE_checksum=4c3bbee33ae61d44bf4323afcb12a0a5
Warning:       gray-axis-invalid

$ colormgr device-add-profile "xrandr-LG Display" \  
/org/freedesktop/ColorManager/profiles/icc_4c3bbee33ae61d44bf4323afcb12a0a5

$
```

... and **I finally have an error free 'device-add-profile'**.

The profile with it's full name (stored in the file) shows up in `Settings > Color > display-name`

*I will be checking whether this makes any difference for printing on my Epson 3880, e.g. from GIMP*