# default color profile for displays

Tags: nvidia, display, color-management

I'm wondering if there's a config parameter or a terminal command that can set all and any future displays that are connected to use an sRGB color calibration profile.

I have a computer that has a Quadro 620 that has a horrible yellow cast, and changing the display calibration profile in settings to sRGB makes the display 'normal'.  I was looking for a way to have this (sRGB) as the default.  Thanks in advance!

Using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and dgm3 within a chrootless LTSP environment.

Comment: Check if this answer might help you... -> https://askubuntu.com/a/1464815/289138

Comment: Thank you.  That link sent me down the right rabbit hole. 

`colormgr get-devices` shows two paths for _Profile 1_ and _Profile 2._
In my case, it was /usr/share/color/icc/colord/...icc and /var/lib/gdm3/.local/share/icc/edid-...icc

Deleting both icc profiles and copying /usr/share/color/icc/colord/sRGB.icc to both locations resolved the issue of having incorrect display colors on a Nvidia Quadro K620 while using Nouveau drivers.

Upon displaying colormgr get-devices once more, only Profile 1 stuck (/usr/share/color/icc/colord/sRGB.icc)  YMMV!